# Scrolling Both horizontally and vertically . how can i show my java code in a code view and scroll my code both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I want to show my java code in a fragment with a code view now my problem is that my code perform only for scrolling down but i want to scroll may code horizontally and vertically at the same time so now what can i do?

i already tried by nesting horizontalscrollview and scrollview but it dose not working and my app gone crush.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="saiful" />

        <thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView
            android:id="@+id/codeViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my java file is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_java, container, false);

    codeView = view.findViewById(R.id.codeViewId);
    codeView.setTheme(CodeViewTheme.ANDROIDSTUDIO).fillColor();
    codeView.showCode(Content.java);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not mess with Horizontal and vertical scrollviews. Here is good [library](https://github.com/tylerfilla/PanView) for that. Give it a try.

"A bidirectional panning container for Android with native scrolling for APIs 7 and up."

Comment: It was worked for me. Its been long when i was asked that question. I am here after 1.5 years to say thank you.

Comment: And here I am after 2.3 years to accept your gratitude